# How to install oracle client on mac?

Tags: oracle, macos

Tried installing oracle client and set path like this

but when i tried to install cx_Oracle it says it couldn't find oracle.

export ORACLE_HOME=/Users/bharatathota/oracle/instantclient_12_1

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME